# Video loop not working

Tags: html, video

I have to reload/refresh my page to see other videos which are in my video array.
I want video is autoplay move on second video after completing first video.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $arrVideo = array('vid1','vid2','vid3');
    shuffle($arrVideo);
    ?>  
<video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
                    <?php 
                    $n=1;
                    foreach($arrVideo as $v){?>
                    <source src="/assets/video/<?php echo $v?>.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                     <?php $n++; }?>
                </video>
```

Kindly Advice me any solution.

Answer (score 1):

`<source>` element is used to provide video or audio encoded in different formats for different browsers. It is not used as playlist.

Here is a link which you can you to achieve your goal.

http://jsfiddle.net/Barzi/Jzs6B/9/

On completion of a video change the source of the video. Use the following code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        // What you want to do after the event
    }
</script>
```